# PHP not sending user back to the actual index.php file

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I came across this weird thing in Jquery Mobile which I can't quite wrap my head around.. When you first enter the site you choose if you want to register or login, when you click on register you get taken to a new page where you fill out your information. When that is done you get sent to `processreg.php` which handles the information and inserts it into the database. This works. After it's done it should take you back to `index.php`, here's where I can't understand what it happening.

**EDIT**: Adding `data-ajax="false"` to the form fixes this issue, HOWEVER, it removes the default page switching effect which I don't intend to remove. Therefore it's not an accepted answer to my question, I've also tried switching via javascript without any luck.

Take a look at this image:

[image: image showing the problem]

This is after you have registrated. The HTML contents of the `index.php` file is there, however, if you look at the URL it's still on `processreg.php`.. So when I try to click on "register" ("registrera dig") I get an error saying it can't load the page, because it tries to load this since we're still on the `processreg.php` page:

```
http://localhost:81/Webb/onlineplatform/includes/includes/pages/register.php
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost:81/Webb/onlineplatform/public/index.php
```

This is the php script that gets run in `processreg.php`:

```
try {
    if (isset($_POST['submit_reg'])) {

        //Script that inserts data into database gets successfully run here

        header('Location: ../../public/index.php');
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

And the `index.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php
    include_once('../includes/files/header.php');
?>

<div data-role="header" class="ui-content no-ellipsis">
    <h1>Jensen Online Yrkeshögskola</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="main">
    <div class="center-wrapper" id="landing-container">
        <h2>Välkommen</h2>
        <p><b>Befintlig användare?</b></p>
        <a href="../includes/pages/login.php" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow" id="login-btn">Logga in</a>
        <p><b>Ny användare?</b></p>
        <a href="../includes/pages/register.php" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow" id="register-btn">Registrera dig</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    include_once('../includes/files/footer.php');
?>
```

As far as I've managed to understand it has something to do with Jquery Mobile using AJAX to switch between different pages but I don't understand how I can tell PHP to send me back to the actual `index.php` and not just grab it's html content and apply it to `processreg.php`. How do I do this?

Comment: **never** use relative address. Always specify the full path starting from the 'root' i.e. "/dir1/dir2" etc. Anything else will be 'confusing'. I have a routine that 'generates' 'absolute urls' to files. Saves a lot of 'hassle'.

Comment: good point, will keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

echo the JS command instead:

```
echo "<script> window.location = 'http://localhost:81/Webb/onlineplatform/public/index.php' </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i've met with same situation. the problem was caching in client side - mobile device try to keep your traffic :-)

try to use new unique link:

```
header('Location: ../../public/index.php?'.base64_encode(rand(0,10000)));
```

or you can try  to clear cache in your mobile app.

if it works - then your problem is detected

so now you can implement caching disable somehow for index.php or for all your pages http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php  :

```
if (isset($_GET['nocache'])) {
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
}
```

and set

```
header('Location: ../../public/index.php?nocache=1');
```

in processreg.php

this should allow index.php be cached, and index.php?nocache=1 - to be always dynamic

Comment: doesn't matter - just generate new link each call how you prefer

Comment: seemed like a solution that would work but I still remain on the same page with the index content loaded.. I've read about how the php must run before any html is sent but how do I do that if I link to a page without any html?

Comment: so that was caching thing?

Comment: " if I link to a page without any html?"  what is the reason of such page? :-) usually you should just say 'hello world' on the page :-)

Comment: Because I like to keep scripts and pure html apart where possible. I don't want to validate and insert on the same page where the html is, it just gets messy. When the script is done it forwards you to a page with html.

Comment: so you can try to set cache off - check updated answer.

Comment: could you provide me a link to your page?\

Comment: I lack a domain at this moment so unfortunately not.

Comment: is it android or iphone ?

Comment: It's more of a computer site rather than for smartphones, I need to learn JQM for a future internship that's why I'm doing it. Difficult when you don't understand all the basics yet though.